New image uploader should have a more descriptive error when you paste in a link rather than a picture
Admittedly, I pretty much tried to fit a square peg into a round hole, but I accidentally used the image upload button instead of the link button when trying to post a link to a question.
Current State

Previous State

This might bite someone who say, tried to use a imgur or other image upload site link they thought was a image but wasn't.
I feel like the error could be more descriptive than "unhandled web exception" - especially if the uploader assumed the link was an image file rather than a link

I don't think "an error occurred" is any more descriptive than "unhandled web exception". In fact I think it's less descriptive. Both are clearly errors, but only one even hints at what kind of exception it is.

@TylerH I think the edit showing previous state was just meant to illustrate that the change didn't necessarily make anything worse, just that both states are similarly unactionable.

Yeah, @AaronBertrand deduced my intent which was at least to document old state since it's not easy for end users to see.  Working on a quick fix that makes this better overall.

I'd just like to say I appreciate the effort both in documenting the previous state (which i honestly had forgotten/never seen) and in looking into a solution to the issue. Well and how painless the move has been so far.

If you try to upload an unsupported filetype, it tells you what filetypes you can upload. This looks like a slightly more useful option. And I didn't try to break it on purpose! tenor lies about file types

Okay, we now have some better error messaging in place.  Depending on the URL, we may either tell you it didn't look enough like a valid image or just that we failed to download it all together



Looks good to me

While "download" is technically correct, I wonder if it would be confusing to people on non-technology-oriented sites. For example someone might see the error message and say "I don't want to download this image, I want to upload this image!". Maybe something like "Failed to fetch image from URL" would be better?

... After I left my previous comment, I just noticed the error message about invalid image types actually uses the word "upload" (i.e. "Please upload a ...") so there is some inconsistency there too. Maybe the verb should instead be something like "use" or "enter" (e.g. "please enter a ...")

I can't check what the previous uploader used to show, so I checked on imgur itself and that's what they show:

The text says:

Sorry, URL failed to upload.

Which is indeed more descriptive than a cryptic "unhandled web exception". Would be better if SE changed to such a message as well, or something along those words.
